# Sharepoint 2003, Backup of Shared Documents Folder

Tags: sharepoint

We have Sharepoint 2003 in our environment to assist the developers to keep their project related documents.

Now, one of the Project want their entire Shared Documents as back up in DVD. The size is approx 3Gb. We tried to map the portal site on local machine as Tools->Map Network Drive->\server\sites\sharepointsite. We then try to copy the folder as Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V on machine. It is not able to copy..it takes around 30 mins as preparing to copy then finally fails.

Could any one please suggest how to take the backup of this folder.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to copy the files by a script, use `xcopy` (see documentation here http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true). This will be better than copy/paste in Windows Explorer, since `xcopy` does not try to calculate the required time for copying, just loops through the file list and copies them.

You could do it with an xcopy script like this:

```
xcopy /S z:\*.* c:\path_where_you_need_the_files\
```

Comment: I am not sure wheather xcopy works for mapped drive..have tried it once..does not work. Will try one more time. Thanks for response.

Comment: before posting this script example, I tested it on my own SharePoint installation. it DID work. ;-)

Comment: Hi, Its working for us also :-)..Will let you know the final outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for the company making the product I am about to mention....

http://www.Attix5.com has a SharePoint backup solution that backs up documents in SharePoint in an incremental manner to an off-site server...